# Should I write a book with third person perspective or first person perspective?

Tags: creative-writing, fiction, creative-commons, english, creativity

I am new to writing and I am starting my first novel which is a love story in 3rd person POV. After writing my first page, I started to think about how to change perspectives and write with the 1st person POV.

Could anyone suggest what works best for this particular genre?

Comment: Probably, yes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Love story, especially when written from the first person narrator can highlight the emotions and inner workings of a character. But if you stick to the first person narrator, you might be confined to not being able to show other people's views (e.g. the person of interest.) That might be your intention, it also gives the readers something to guess about as the reader is confined to the insights of the first person narrator.
An omnicient narrator (usually a third person narrator, though there are lots of variances), is usually written in the 3rd person. This narrator has insight (as (s)he chooses) into any character and conveys the information to the reader. Here you can "hop" from character to character and show their inner workings, ideas or you might only want to convey more restricted information (only what one can see or the like, or only certain characters at certain points of time.)

You are the author, you are in control. This is your story. Experiment with what works best for you, because the only person you are truly writing for - is yourself. Sometimes others will like it, sometimes they won't. You can work on your strategies, but in the end - it must be yours and make you happy.

I hope some of the ideas will help you. Experiment with various writing styles!

"I was looking at the movie and thinking why am I watching this movie, when I could do so much more" (1st person narrator)

"There he was watching another movie, thinking, he could do so much more." (3rd person narrator, omniscient.)

"There he was watching a movie, looking indifferent, unsatisfied." (3rd person narrator, focused on the outside.)

Comment: +1 on Experiment. There's absolutely no reason why OP would have to decide on a perspective on page 1. Just pick whichever feels best right now, and after you've written the first chapter, check whether it still works.

Comment: Please read the paragraph which says: You are the author, you are in control. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. this information will help me writing better